# Working with large data sets and ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

Could REALLY use some help here.  Struggling with displaying a dashboard with large data.

When working with @ 2k records average @ 2 sec.

The query in MySql Console take less than 3.5 seconds to return 150k rows.  Same query in Ruby takes over 4 + minutes from time query is performed until all objects and ready.

Goal: Optimize data even further before adding cache server.  Working with Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0 and Mysql (Mysql2 gem)

Questions:

- Does working with Hashes hurt performance?
- Should I first put everything in one primary hash then manipulate the data I need afterwards?
- Is there anything else I can do to help with performance?

Rows in DB:

- GasStations and US Census has @ 150,000 records
- Person has @ 100,000 records
- Cars has @ 200,000 records
- FillUps has @ 2.3 Million

Required for dashboard (query based on time periods of last 24 hours, last week, etc).  All data returned in JSON format for JS.

- Gas Stations, with FillUps and US Census data (zip code, Name, City, Population)
- Top 20 cities with the most fill ups
- Top 10 cars with Fill Ups
- Cars grouped by how many times they filled up their tank

Code (sample of 6 months.  Returns @ 100k + records):

```
# for simplicity, removed the select clause I had, but removing data I don't need like updated_at, gas_station.created_at, etc. instead of returning all the columns for each table.
@primary_data = FillUp.includes([:car, :gas_staton, :gas_station => {:uscensus}]).where('fill_ups.created_at >= ?', 6.months.ago) # This would take @ 4 + minutes

# then tried

@primary_data = FillUp.find_by_sql('some long sql query...') # took longer than before.
# Note for others, sql query did some pre processing for me which added attributes to the return.  Query in DB Console took < 4 seconds.  Because of these extra attributes, query took longer as if Ruby was checking each row for mapping attributes

# then tried

MY_MAP = Hash[ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all('SELECT thingone, thingtwo from table').map{|one| [one['thingone'], one['thingtwo']]}] as seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456834/ruby-on-rails-storing-and-accessing-large-data-sets
# that took 23 seconds and gained mapping of additional data that was processing later, so much faster

# currently using below which takes @ 10 seconds
# All though this is faster, query still only takes 3.5 seconds, but parsing it to the hashes does add overhead.
cars = {}
gasstations = {}
cities = {}
filled = {}

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
client.query("SELECT sum(fill_ups_grouped_by_car_id) as filled, fillups.car_id, cars.make as make, gasstations.name as name,  ....", :stream => true, :as => :json).each do |row|
  # this returns fill ups gouged by car ,fill_ups.car_id, car make, gas station name, gas station zip, gas station city, city population 
  if cities[row['city']]
    cities[row['city']]['fill_ups']  = (cities[row['city']]['fill_ups']  + row['filled'])
  else
    cities[row['city']] = {'fill_ups' => row['filled'], 'population' => row['population']}
  end
  if gasstations[row['name']]
    gasstations[row['name']]['fill_ups'] = (gasstations[row['name']]['fill_ups'] + row['filled'])
  else
    gasstations[row['name']] = {'city' => row['city'],'zip' => row['city'], 'fill_ups' => row['filled']}
  end
  if cars[row['make']]
    cars[row['make']] = (cars[row['make']] + row['filled'])
  else
    cars[row['make']] = row['filled']
  end
  if row['filled']
    filled[row['filled']] = (filled[row['filled']] + 1)
  else
    filled[row['filled']] = 1
  end
end
```

Have the following models:

```
def Person
 has_many :cars 
end

def Car
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :uscensus, :foreign_key => :zipcode, :primary_key => :zipcode
  has_many :fill_ups
  has_many :gas_stations, :through => :fill_ups
end

def GasStation
  belongs_to :uscensus, :foreign_key => :zipcode, :primary_key => :zipcode
  has_many :fill_ups
  has_many :cars, :through => :fill_ups
end

def FillUp
  # log of every time a person fills up there gas
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :gas_station
end

def Uscensus
  # Basic data about area based on Zip code
end
```

Comment: Nitpicking here: `Car`, `GasStation`, `FillUp`. IMHO it is much nicer the Ruby convention: `car`, `gas_station`, `fill_up`

Comment: Is it a requirement to return the entire data set first vs. something like http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_in_batches

Comment: Nope, can do find_in_batches but the ruby method was extremely slow.  Will try and report back results.

Comment: As for "Nicer", I agree and easier to read but performance is key

Comment: OK, did quick test pulling id, city and fipscode from us census table with 149,318 rows:  -- Standard Ruby: 149318 and took: 6.144613, -- Finding in Batches: 149318 and took: 6.642666, -- Mysql GEM Raw Query: 149318 and took: 1.851102

Comment: to add further performance changed :as => :json to :as => :array which helped slightly more.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use RoR, but returning 100k rows for a dashboard is never going to be very fast.  I strongly suggest building or maintaining summary tables and run `GROUP BY`s in the database to summarize your dataset before presentation.

Comment: We tried "Roll up" tables but that started getting messy because we write large chunks of new data every 15 min so all rollups would need to be updated every 15 min too.

Comment: Still, every 15 minutes might be better than every time you update the dashboard.  Whatever you do, I'd try to keep the rollup on the database side.